# Octopus - Steps to take code backup on server (tentacle) before deployment

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I have created a new release on Octopus server to deploy the code on live tentacle virtual machine (in Azure environment). It all works okay.
I would like to know the steps to take code backup in another folder on the live tentacle node before deploying new code on to it. Not sure how to do this. I am new to power shell. Thanks.

Comment: What sort of application are you deploying?

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind Octopus is that all deployments are repeatable, including older versions. The code you deployed for previous versions lives on the Octopus server (depending on how you setup your retention policies) so you can deploy it again.

The default manner of [installing to IIS](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/iis-websites-and-application-pools#IISWebsitesandApplicationPools-HowOctopusDeploysyourWebSite) is to leave the previous deployment alone and deploy to a new folder and update IIS to point to the new version.